# Custom Shapes are gigantic

Tags: bones

I've been having a lot of trouble with doing custom shapes for my bones. I think I know where the issue stems from: I had to change the size of my armature because I switched unit types and wanted my mesh to be measured in metric/centimeters to reflect real life size. Thus changing something? I had to make the armature bigger to accommodate the real life size.

Does anyone know how I could fix this without having to edit the small plane (the plane) until it is in the position and size that I want? (Plane is an example I set up not indicative of the shape I want)

Thank you very much for any help you attempt to provide.
[image]

Image is of after I orient custom shape. Before I do the custom shape (plane) is just as the wireframe.

Comment: When you change size in object mode always apply the changes (Ctrl+A) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: I already applied it.

Moreover I tried updating blender to see if it had a solution and now its in this weird new UI that doesn't work and I can't open my file in the old version again. I've been crying all morning because I've lost weeks of work. I just wanted some custom shapes. Now all I want is for Blender to work again instead of this awful UI where I can't do anything. And any file type I export it as won't let me keep my old model.